# MongoDB compute fields from 2 subdocuments and produce new document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have collection that hold 2 subdocuments `fsgeneral` and `balancesheet`. In order to compute the Book Value for different `fye`, I will have take the value `balancesheet.shareholderFund` / `fsgeneral.dilutedShares`.

The question is it possible to use aggregate to do this and how can this be achieved?

My input collection as below:

```
 {
  "counter": "APPLE",
  "fsgeneral": {
    "0": {
      "fye": "Mar-01",
      "dilutedShares": {
        "value": 10
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "fye": "Mar-02",      
      "dilutedShares": {
        "value": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "balancesheet": {
    "0": {
      "fye": "Mar-01",
      "shareholderFund": {
        "value": 200
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "fye": "Mar-02",
      "shareholderFund": {
        "value": 400
      }
    }
 }
```

Expected result:

```
 {
  "counter": "APPLE",
  "output": {
    "0": {
      "fye": "Mar-01",
      "bookvalue": {
        "value": 20
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "fye": "Mar-02",      
      "bookvalue": {
        "value": 40
      }
    }
  }  
 }
```

I have tried a few aggregates but failed to come to how 2 subdocuments can be used at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$objectToArray` convert object to array and input in `$map`, $map will iterate loop,
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `fsgeneral` and check key matches with `balancesheet` then divide using `$divide`
- `$arrayToObject`, `$map` will return array and this will convert to again object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      counter: 1
      output: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$balancesheet" },
            as: "a",
            in: {
              k: "$$a.k",
              v: {
                fye: "$$a.v.fye",
                bookvalue: {
                  value: {
                    $reduce: {
                      input: { $objectToArray: "$fsgeneral" },
                      initialValue: 0,
                      in: {
                        $cond: [
                          { $eq: ["$$this.k", "$$a.k"] },
                          { $divide: ["$$a.v.shareholderFund.value", "$$this.v.dilutedShares.value"] },
                          "$$value"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0GQEQzsnyWq)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. btw, if i have another value that i need to generate lets say `bookvalue2` which will based on different field in `balancesheet`. i will need to run $reduce twice on this to generate `bookvalue` and `bookvalue2`. is that the only way for this?

Comment: I think no you can do it in same $reduce, just updated a example field called bookvalue2 [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h9AoRwn7Nj0)

Comment: Can i know what is actually happening at `$$value` inside the `$reduce`. Is it because when the condition matched then $$value will be assigned to the divided value, but the loop still going on and $$value get assigned to $$value in other condition?

Comment: While reduce have 3 fields (input, initialValue, in) `input`: can allow array input, so basically it will iterate loop as per number of elements of array field from input, ex: a array has 2 element then it will iterate loop 2 time inside `in` property of reduce, but the main thing is reduce will return 1 time, so reduce can manage one temporary variable inside `initialValue` property, you can define any return type in initialValue, but it can hold a temporary value inside `$$value`  also we can manage internal conversation as per our login inside initialValue.

Comment: Now in your question, we are checking condition when condition match it will execute $divide process, and this divide process will return in reduce's default initialValue ($$value) and when second iteration condition false it will return and replace same value from defualt initialValue $$value to same initialValue ($$value), means value remains same when condition false.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. hows about if the above input collection has more records and is there a way to improvise on the aggregate to select only record "2" to "3". i have tried to use filter but no idea how to filter by string "2" to "3", https://mongoplayground.net/p/gczZQ8tMe6Y

Comment: You can use $slice to select number of records from array like this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B1LfCqPCJ3o), i have entered 3 then it will return 3 obects.

Comment: Tried that but seems like my document 0 is currently at the end of array [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ONF64vqXHXb). How do i make sure that the document should be from 0 to n in ascending order? tried $sort inside $slice but with errors.